# Is there a way to see how long I've spent playing any particular game?

Tags: ps4

I'm curious to find out how long I've been playing No Mans Sky, and there's nothing that I can see in-game that would tell me that. So I was wondering if there's a global Playstation 4 data / stats screen somewhere that tells me the duration I've spend playing any single game.

I thought the trophies screen would help here, but that only lists out the trophies, nothing more generic and stats based. And the [PSN website](https://secure.eu.playstation.com/psn/mypsn/) is not any better. It's all pretty barren.

Is there any way to find this out? (Not with NMS specifically, but any game).

Comment: I joined just to say that this is my favorite "first world problem" of the year.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_World_problem

Answer (score 5):

The only way to see gameplay hours of any game is if there is an option in-game. There is no way to see this on the PS4 home menu with a nice hourly breakdown per game.

Based on comments in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/PS4/comments/2hs64k/how_to_tell_how_many_hours_youve_played_a_game/#bottom-comments), it looks like Destiny and Trials Fusion store gameplay hours, for instance.

A side note, this past week, in Sony's *lovely* Weekly Update email, they informed me of my total gameplay hours on my PSN account, so it looks like they DO store gameplay hours, but there's no way to access them.

[image: I really didn't need to know this number]

Comment: Roughly 483.5 days for those curious.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff the worst part is that this account was created January 2012

Comment: FWIW, I don't know about PS4, but on account that many games reload saves on game overs, in-game counters are often underestimations. Sometimes astoundingly so. They shouldn't be trusted at all.

Comment: I'm assuming that a total gameplay hour counter for PSN would work the same as it does for steam, where hours accumulate as long as the game is open and running. Also, are you trying to suggest that I've spent MORE than 483 days playing games in the past 4-5 years?

Comment: @vemonus that's a full time job equivalent for 5.4 years or so (given 22 work day months and 8 hour workdays) so if that is an underestimation it's scary.

Comment: "it's just a hobby"